# JSON data not appearing in QTableModel

Tags: python, json, qml

I created a table using qml, I wanted to add JSON data inside the table. The problem is that I can only see the last row of json data for e.g. if I added a new entry then I can only see that entry not the pervious ones.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as OldControls
import QtQml.Models 2.15
import TbModel 1.0


OldControls.ApplicationWindow {
id: window
visible: true
width: 1900
height: 600

OldControls.TableView
{
    id: idtable
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    model: TbModel{ }
    OldControls.TableViewColumn {
        role: "customer_id"
        title: "customer_id"
    }
    OldControls.TableViewColumn {
        role: "customer_code"
        title: "customer_code"
    }
    OldControls.TableViewColumn {
        role: "customer_name"
        title: "customer_name"
    }

    OldControls.TableViewColumn {
        role: "contact"
        title: "contact"
    }

    OldControls.TableViewColumn {
        role: "address"
        title: "address"
    }
}
}
```

Table.py

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QObject, Qt, Slot
import requests
import json

class TbModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: QObject = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.headers = ["customer_id", "customer_code", "customer_name", "contact", "address"] 
        r = requests.get("http://192.168.10.5:8085/api/customer") # api I created 
        x = r.json()
        for i in x:
            self.rows = [
               (i["customer_id"], i["customer_code"], i["customer_name"], i["contact"], 
   i["address"]),
               (i["customer_id"], i["customer_code"], i["customer_name"], i["contact"], 
   i["address"])

    ]

def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return len(self.rows)

def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    row = index.row()
    if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
        if role in self.roleNames():
            name_role = self.roleNames()[role].decode()
            col = self.headers.index(name_role)
            return self.rows[row][col]

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole and 0 <= section < len(self.headers):
        return self.headers[section]

def roleNames(self):
    roles = {}
    for i, header in enumerate(self.headers):
        roles[Qt.UserRole + i + 1] = header.encode()
    return roles

@Slot(result="QVariantList")
def roleNameArray(self):
    return self.headers
```

main.py

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql, QtQml
from Table import TbModel
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    QtQml.qmlRegisterType(TbModel, "TbModel", 1, 0, "TbModel")

    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I don't know why it's showing only the most recent results, I could understand if it showed me the first result (which would most likely indicate that I need to use a loop). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a late response. I figured out the problem, basically I was overwriting the content of self.rows with each iteration of the loop. I needed to append rather than replace.